# $('#display).text() returning as [object%20Object]

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get what's inside a `<div>` with ID of `display` using

```
$("#display").after(html);
var testxd = $("#display").text();
window.location.replace("test.php?v="+testxd);
```

and all I get is a BLANK. I Help?

Here is div `display`:

```
<div id="display" style="display: none;"></div>
```

I know the ID is in the because the ID shows up during `after(html)`;

Comment: Your `display` div has no content and you're only inserting content after it.  Why (and how) would you expect to get anything other than an empty string from `text()`?

Comment: You might be interested in looking at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/WDrXP/

Comment: "I know the ID is in the because the ID shows up during `after(html)`;" I have no idea what this means. Anyone?

Comment: Thanks tvanfosson, I got it! :D

Comment: Here's my result: http://pastebin.com/SHJFTBLi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no text inside the `<div id="display"></div>` so blank is the result.

If you had

```
<div id="display">foo</div>
```

then you would get "foo" from $("#display").text();

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `append`, not `after`. You're adding content *after* `#display`, not *into* it.

This means that your `<div>` in fact remains empty, so of course `.text()` returns an empty string.